# changed ownership on mysql files. How can I recover database?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ownership, data-recovery

I am using digitalocean  VPS. Accidentally I changed all files' ownership to www-data on my server. How can I get my mysql database copy from this server?

Comment: All files? As in you did a `chown` on `/`? If so, MySQL isn't going to be the only thing that's affected. SSH probably won't let you back in, so don't log out...

Comment: SSH is not affected. I checked all files is changes but I can login with ssh.

Answer (score 2):

No backups? MySQL files should be in /var/lib/mysql or /var/db/mysql... look around, you may be able to change the ownership of those files and get mysql to start again, dump the db and start anew on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new vps with digitalocean and installed mysql.
Then copied file permissions and owners from new vps to old vps. 
Mysql worked again on old machine!